# Looking for Xcode Compilation Monitor

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, clang, clang++

I am trying to identify which translation unit in my Xcode C++ project takes too much time. Therefore I am looking for a way to visualize the compilation process. Any ideas for Xcode 9 or Xcode 10?

On Windows there is a distribution compile system called IncrediBuild, which has a nice visualization. Any chance to find something similar on Mac? If not, any ideas what I could do to identify which translation units or dependencies during a compile take too much time?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to identify which translation unit in my Xcode C++ project takes too much time.

Check Xcode's Report Navigator. You can select the report for a given build and see a list of all the build steps and the time taken for each one, so you can see which one(s) take the most time. It's not a visualization, but it does give you the information you need to find the files that take a long time to compile, link, etc.

Select the Report Navigator, and then click on the particular build that you want to look at. You'll see a list of the parts of the build, like "Prepare to build" and "Build MyProject", with disclosure triangles next to each. Click the disclosure triangle for the "Build MyProject" (it'll obviously be named with the name of the actual target, not "MyProject"), and you'll see a list of the individual build steps and times.